# Angular 2: Allow hash in route path

Tags: angular2-routing

If I have a route path with a hash, when I navigate to it, the hash is dropped from the URL and the page redirects to default path.

Ex:
http://localhost:4200/secure-headless/abc#/sample/wizard redirects to http://localhost:4200/#/sample/wizard

Is there a way to allow hash in the route using pathLocationStrategy?

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 2: Allow hash in route path**

1. replace **"start": "ng serve --base-href=/secure-headless/abc"** under "scripts" in **package.json**. (refer screenshot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbT3N.png
2. In root modules, define **"{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }"** under **providers**. (refer screenshot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiQXV.png